# How to rewrite my code so that I dont repeat myself, i.e. as in the DRY principle

Tags: java

```
if (c < n) {
  while (c != n) {
    p *= b;
    c++;
  }
}else if (c > n){
  while (c != n) {
    p *= b;
    c--;
  }
  p = 1.0/p;
}
```

I think boolean might help but I have no idea how to implement it.

Comment: Yes something like this?
s =flase
if (c < n) {
  s= true
}
while (c != n) {
   p *= b;
 if(s){
   c++
 }else{
   c--
}

  }
 p = 1.0/p;

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

A boolean would work, or you can set an int adjuster for `c` and kill two birds with one stone:

```
if (c != n) {
  int x = c < n ? 1 : -1;
  while (c != n) {
    p *= b;
    c += x;
  }
  if (x == -1) {
    p = 1.0/p;
  }
}
```